# Infinite Set confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given an infinite set $A$, I want to show that there exists some subset $B$ of $A$ such that $|A| = |B|$. This is the definition of an infinite set.

I can create examples of this, but I am confused on how to prove it generally. I let $A$ contain something like $x_0, x_1, x_2,  \dots$ then...what? That is, how do I show that there is a bijection without having a specific set $A$ to work with. Doing this generally is what is confusing me.

Comment: Try to find a bijection between sets $A$ and $B$, showing they have the same cardinality.

Comment: Obviously, but my question is how I should go about doing that generally.

Comment: What is **your** definition of "infinite set", @ylomn ?

Comment: @Timbuc A set which is not finite.

Comment: by the definition of infinite, you can find $\mathbb{N}$ in A?
If you do this, you're done

Comment: Let $B=A$ and use the identity map.

Answer (score 1):

With the Axion of Choice, construnct an injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$:

$f(0)=$ random element in $A$

$f(1)=$ random element in $A-\{f(0)\}$

...

Since $A$ is infinite, $A$ without a finite number of elements is always non-empty, so you can construct $f$.

If $f(n)=x_n$, and $C$ is the set of $x_n$, then let $B=A-\{x_0\}$

Define now a bijective function $g:A\to B$ such that

$g(x)=x$ if $x\notin C$

$g(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ for all $x_n$ in $C$

So $|B|=|A|$